# Excel Formula Help - Formula that will return the bold number above ID parallel to data. Example Included

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Background Fluff**
For work I receive these painfully formatted data sets in excel where the ID of the product is ABOVE the data in question, when it really should be alongside the data so I can filter it. This is something I have done manually in the past, but it takes a very long time as the data sets are vast. I'm looking for a way to expedite the process. I've been battling with my own knowledge, ChatGPT and Google Bard to try and figure this out, but the results are always incorrect in some way.

[image: example]

**Question**
What I need is a formula I can drag down the entire document from A1 and B1, that will return the results above the adjacent "ID" and "Length". Using the example picture, the green text is the formula cells and results. "111" and "Thing 1" are being pulled from C1 and D1. If the formula doesn't need to show this data, it should return blank "".

**Approach**
The formulas I've tried using IF statements and INDEX to locate the data above the cell with the content "ID", then work from there. As "ID" is always present and in the correct position/pattern it helped to anchor the formula. I also tried searching for `ISNUMBER` and a VB script `ISBOLD` for formatting, but this didn't help much.

I'm hoping someone can provide a solution, I feel like I've tried every possible approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think this works in A3 and copied down and across `=IF(C3="","",(IF($C2="ID",C1,A2)))`

Comment: Bam! Instant solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: More evidence that ChatGPT, Bard etc are surprisingly useless...

Comment: Thanks for the additional responses all. These are some fascinating solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have got an easy and simple solution from **[SJR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7008044/sjr)**, which is needs to fill down and works across all **`Excel Versions`** that said the formula provided is :

```
=IF(C3="","",(IF($C2="ID",C1,A2)))
```

---

The above formula as stated in comments by the SJR needs to enter in cell <kbd>A3</kbd> and to be filled down & filled right, but if you have are using **`MS365`** then you could try using the following formula, which spills.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, C1:C21,
     b, C1:D21,
     c, IF(a="","",SCAN(0,a,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y<>"",x,x+1)))+1),
     d, INDEX(b,XMATCH(c,c,0),{1,2}),
     IF((b="")+(a="ID")+(b=d),"",d))
```

---

### A Friendly Suggestion

Don't use any **volatile functions**, as <kbd>OFFSET( )</kbd> is a flexible function and it can point to a different-sized range that is calculated on-the-fly. But it is a **volatile function**. If you go to a completely unrelated cell and enter a number, all of the <kbd>OFFSET( )</kbd> functions will calculate—even if that cell has nothing to do with.

It has been found, Excel is very careful to spend time calculating the cells that needs to be calculated. But once you use the <kbd>OFFSET( )</kbd>, all of the <kbd>OFFSET( )</kbd> cells, plus everything downline from the <kbd>OFFSET()</kbd>, starts calculating after every change in the worksheet.

Why it matters ? <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> is not volatile( <kbd>INDEX()</kbd> function used in the above formula provided to return all the `111`s and `Things`. You enjoy all of the flexible goodness of <kbd>OFFSET( )</kbd> without the time-sucking recalculations over and over.

---

A quick .gif on the above solution, with a tiny modification,

[image]

---

**Updated Formula :** --> It assumes `Column C` will always have a value till the last row, and can be taken as a reference as well.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _lastRow, MATCH(10^3, 1/(C:C<>"")),
     a, C1:INDEX(C:C,_lastRow),
     b, C1:INDEX(C:D,_lastRow,0),
     c, IF(a="","",SCAN(0,a,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y<>"",x,x+1)))+1),
     d, INDEX(b,XMATCH(c,c,0),{1,2}),
     e, IF((b="")+(a="ID")+(b=d),"",d),
     e)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by combining the `IFERROR()`, `IF()`, `OFFSET()` and `AND` functions.

**Dataset**:
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKmSj.png)

**Step 1**: Select cell `A1`, insert the following formula, drag the fill handle icon to `A20`.

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(OFFSET(C1,-1,0)="ID",C1<>""),OFFSET(C1,-2,0),IF(AND(OFFSET(C1,-2,0)="ID",C1<>""),OFFSET(C1,-3,0),IF(AND(OFFSET(C1,-3,0)="ID",C1<>""),OFFSET(C1,-4,0),""))),"")
```

[Select cell A1, insert the given formula and drag the formula down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JuwK.png)

**Step 2**: Select cell `B1`, insert the following formula, drag the fill handle icon to `B20`.

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(OFFSET(D1,-1,0)="Length",D1<>""),OFFSET(D1,-2,0),IF(AND(OFFSET(D1,-2,0)="Length",D1<>""),OFFSET(D1,-3,0),IF(AND(OFFSET(D1,-3,0)="Length",D1<>""),OFFSET(D1,-4,0),""))),"")
```

[Select cell B1, insert the given formula and drag the formula down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEzGQ.png)

***Limitation**: These formulas will not return the desired values if more than three rows are under each ID and Length section.*