# How can I loop thru a column of grouped values in Excel VBA and create a helper column that identifies the group id for each subcategory below it?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I’m trying to return the values in column A (RESULT). Not sure if this can be done through a formula or is necessary to do using VBA, either one would suffice. Column A (RESULT) is a helper column that I would like to use for returning the group id in column B for each subcategory below it (please see example pic below for what I'm trying to return in column A). Doing so will allow me to associate each subcategory more effectively and easily to the group id when dealing with a large dataset. Thank you!

[image: RESULT example pic]

Comment: How about `=IF(C2="",B2,IF(C3<>"",A2,""))` and drag down?

Comment: This already has a solution. Using Dynamic array formula, [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77261903/8162520) --> Duplicate post

Comment: Thank you all for your quick replies and helpful solutions! However, I agree with user Mayukh Bhattacharya, @BigBen provided the easiest solution to use. Thank you @BigBen!! This works beautifully!

Answer (score 2):

The formula suggested by [BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) Sir, is the easiest one to use and it works perfectly as is needed. However, if one need to use a dynamic array formula to spill all the once then could try the following as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, C2:C19,
     b, FILTER(B2:B19,a=""),
     c, IF(a="",NA(),SCAN(0,a,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y<>"",x,x+1)))),
     IFNA(XLOOKUP(c, UNIQUE(TOCOL(c,2)),b),""))
```

---